# Get top row my MySQL as fast as possible (also on large tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I have a simple software for an industrial machine which operates using MySQL as data storage. There is only one connection and one user on the database at any time.

My table is simple:

```
id   data            fetched 
int  varchar         boolean

1     KDINNALSKDGJ     0
2     F34LNALNLIJA     0
```

etc. id is always sequential, and has an index.

What I need is to is always get the first "data" (with lowest id) where fetched is 0. Then update "fetched" to be "1" because I received the data.

I use something like

```
SELECT id, data FROM mytable WHERE fetched=0 LIMIT 0,1
```

This works, but get sequentially slower for each call. This is my real problem. I can live with the estimated 0,005 seconds for the first 100 or so, but at 50.000+ I am up against 0,3 seconds.

I assume this is because the database searches from the top every time finding first that matches.

Constraining index by number is a lot faster:

```
SELECT id, data FROM mytable WHERE id> :myLastID  and fetched=0 LIMIT 0,1
```

.. but this also slows down after 40.000 or so, at 80.000 I am around 20 msec (first around 6 msec)

My final database may be in the millions-range, but typically could be around 2-500.000

Is there any way I can make MySQL return "next record" faster ? Using a CURSOR from MySQL ?

I will be using Delphi to interface to MySQL. I tried both a stored procedure and using 2 queries to select /update. Almost same result.

Comment: Have you tried the 'TOP'. I do not know does it work for MySQL, however it should.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: It seems like you need an UPDATE, not a SELECT

Comment: There are architectural ways around this problem (caching, different tables etc..), but we'd need to know a bit more about the problem: 1) is the DB on the same cpu as the s/w for the machine? 2) are there generally many more 0 than 1 cases (or vice versa)? 3) is the machine s/w blocked by the DB operations? etc... So, can you sketch the problem with a few more details, please? If it cannot be solved by a MySQL command, you might be looking at re-structuring your architecture.

Comment: @P2000 the database is on the same machine, but can be on a different is that's faster. All "fetched" start out _false_, the field is a check if that number has been used. I do not need just an update, I do need updateSelect, since I use the sequence in data.

The software is not blocked, but if the response is late, some physical items may get out of sync (or are forced to run at lower pace). While this is possible, I would like to aim for a cycle time of 25 msec. This leaves quite short time for my DB. 

If it's not possible to speed up, I may have to rethink, as you mention.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "I use the sequence in data". So that aside, is it possible to get a bunch of unfetched "data" at once, and cache them, perhaps by copying them to an array or to a separate cache table? This would reduce the frequency of queries on a large table. Also,  if you don't use "fetched" "data" more than once, maybe you can purge the table from time to time (in chunks) by deleting fetched data or moving it to a different table. The performance of course depends on your specific use case, incl. how the CPU & drive are loaded by the DB vs the S/W.

Comment: @P2000 I have to keep the data, since I will make a report later. There are more processes to the data than just "fetched" - could also be "processed" and "verified".

I think I will eventually end up with the "make a query for large chunk" and then update in batches with transaction. Risking of course inconsistency at power loss, which I tried to prevent with the single query idea.

Comment: Yes power interruptions are a problem if you cache on volatile memory, which is where S/W structures/vars go, of course. You could mirror the loaded cache/chunk "array" in a DB table. If the mirroring is in a concurrent thread, you minimize your latency problems. I'm guessing you know this: even the DB might not be safe if the OS is still buffering R/W in memory. Power interruptions are best handled at the H/W level with a UPS and power-down interrupts, to exit in a known and safe state (servers, medical equipment, machinery, military equipment...)

Answer (score 3):

As a starter: your query needs an `order by` clause, otherwise it is actually undefined which row will be returned first (there is no guarantee that it will be the row with the smallest `id`).

So you should phrase this as:

```
select id, data 
from mytable 
where fetched = 0 
order by id
limit 1
```

Then for performance, I would recommend adding the following index:

```
create index myindex on mytable(fetched, id, data)
```

The logic is:

- the first column of the index, `fetched`, matches the predicates in the `where` clause
- the second column is the ordering column (`id`)
- the third column is the remaining column in the `select` clause (`data`)

This gives you a *covering index*: MySQL should be able to execute the whole query by looking at the index only (ie without looking at the data itself).

Comment: Thank for for the suggestions. I did implement them, but strangely the performance (time per query) was about the same.  My guess is that without looking at different strategies, I can't get the performance on "selectUpdate" I require. The time increases on my SQL server to around 50 msec.  Your suggestion is welcomed though.

Comment: I would avoid adding `data` to the index. First, it will make the index much bigger, Second, since you need to update the record, you will need to access the data anyway.

Comment: @MyICQ You should use `EXPLAIN` to check how MySQL executes the query. It should be fast if the correct index is used.

Comment: I have the impression that "data" is a unique token, and so "id" and "data" are independently unique. If so, this means that the index only needs to span "id" and "fetched". Including "data" would offset the benefits of indexing, which may be what the OP is observing.

Comment: @P2000: no - this is the last column in the index, so even if it is unique that's not a problem (that would be if it was firt in the index). This still gives you a usuable and covering index - which is what we want here to speed up the query.

Comment: @MyICQ: possibly, the benefit of the index is overcomed by the fact that you now use `order by` (as you should have initially...).  You might want to compare how the query *with the `order by`* behaves with or without the index.

Comment: @GMB ok that's new to me, I didn't realize the order matters. Do you have a good reference for this? Maybe just the manual? Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** there is only one connection may we then also assume there is only one 'user' too?
If so, why not simply keep the id value in memory of the program and ask for the first next number by simply asking for the 'next' record. E.g. `SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = @x AND fetched = 0`? If nothing is returned then you know the value was already fetched before and something got out of sync (or the table ran out of records). This should be exceptional and you'd have to revert back to your old query to get back on track I guess, but again, it should be exceptional.

Wouldn't require any other changes (I'm assuming id is the PK when you say 'index')

PS: since you don't mention it, does InnoDB vs MyISAM make a difference? (I'd prefer the former from what I've read but TBH I have pretty much no practical experience with either)

And oh yeah, as others already mentioned, `LIMIT 1` without an `ORDR BY` will pretty much give you "random results". This might be on purpose but that's rare and most situations prefer having the same results when re-running.